# How to Insert Core Data Record Related to Another Without Duplication

Tags: objective-c, core-data, one-to-many, relationship, duplication

I have two core data entities, `Articles` and `Favorite`. `Articles` has To-Many relationship to `Favorite`. First, I inserted all `Articles` object successfully.

Now, I'm trying to insert ArticleID in  “Favorite” entity but I cant. Either the record is inserted with an empty relationship or it is inserted with new record in “Articles” entity.

I think that I should be getting the related record in `Articles` entity first and then using it to insert in `Favorite` but I'm not sure how to do this. My current code:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context =[appDelegate managedObjectContext] ; 
favorite *Fav =[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"favorite" inManagedObjectContext:context];
Articles * Article = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Articles" inManagedObjectContext:context];

NSError *error;

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init]; 
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                               entityForName:@"Articles" inManagedObjectContext:context];  
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity]; 
NSPredicate *secondpredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"qid = %@",appDelegate.GlobalQID ];
NSPredicate *thirdpredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"LangID=%@",appDelegate.LangID]; 
NSPredicate *comboPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: secondpredicate,thirdpredicate, nil]]; 
[fetchRequest setPredicate:comboPredicate];
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
for (NSManagedObject *info in fetchedObjects) { 
        // ?????????????????????????

    }

}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating new Article object:

```
Articles *NewObj = [fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
```

and use it to insert relationship :

```
    [Fav setFavArticles:NewObj];
     [NewObj setArticlesFav:Fav];
```

thanks very much TechZen..

Answer (score 4):

First, make sure you have a reciprocal i.e. two way relationship between `Article` and `Favorite`. Something like this:

```
Article{
  favorites<-->>Favorite.article
}

Favorite{
  article<<-->Article.favorites
}
```

Defining reciprocal relationships in Core Data means that setting the relationship from one side automatically sets it for the other.

So, to set a new `Favorite` object for a newly created `Article` object you would just:

```
Favorite *fav =[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"favorite" inManagedObjectContext:context];
Articles *article = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Articles" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[article.addFavoriteObject:fav];
//... or if you don't use custom NSManagedObject subclasses
[[article mutableSetValueForKey:@"favorites"] addObject:fav];
```

If either the `Article` object or the `Favorite` object already exist, you would fetch the object first but setting the relationship would work exactly the same way.

The key is to make sure you have the reciprocal relationship so that the managed object context knows to set the relationship in both objects.

Comment: Thanks TechZen..
I have already inversed relationship between Articles and  favorite ..
the object of   Articles is inserted previously and now I want to insert related  favorite  object .
I have added this line into loop :
[[Fatwa mutableSetValueForKey:@"FavArticle"] addObject:Fav];

and get this  error  :

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Articles 0xc9dfec0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: the entity Article is not key value coding-compliant for the key "FavFArticle".'


 how to use fetched Articles  object to insert favorite object ??..

Comment: The error means that you don't have an attribute called/spelled "FavArticle" defined for the `Articles` entity/class. This is usually just the result of a typo that causes you to misspell the key name e.g. the real name is something like "favArticle" or "favArticles".

Comment: Why does the relationship from Article to Favorite is 1-> N?

Comment: Because that is what the parent post's author said it was. The relationship doesn't have to be 1->N and the reciprocal doesn't have to be 1->1 but that is the most common pattern.